# PayPal chectout returns UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

Tags: paypal, checkout

My checkout code

```
let ORDERPRICE = 2;
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            application_context: {
                shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
                brand_name: "MYCOMP",
                user_action: 'PAY_NOW',
                payment_method: {
                    payee_preferred: 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED'
                }
            },
            payer: {
                name: {
                    given_name: 'NAME'
                },
                email_address: 'EMAIL@EMAIL.com'
            },
            purchase_units: [{
                description: "description",
                amount: {
                    currency_code: 'EUR',
                    value: ORDERPRICE
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          //submitting my form to show thank you page
        var sentform = document.getElementById('booking-sent');
        sentform.submit();
      });
    },
    style: {
                color:  'blue'
            }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

In a browser debug i see a POST to https://www.paypal.com/smart/api/order/23H57866L56525306/capture And i get an answer from PayPal

```
    {"ack":"contingency","contingency":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","data":
    {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","description":"The request was refused"}],
"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"282422b19213c",
    "links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-TRANSACTION_REFUSED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]},"meta":{"calc":"282422b19213c","rlog":"rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAcnM25I5c5rd3HxcyHxUk51TwoDOk%2By6wR%2Bw1HIUZ5ikN_17823c767ad"},"server":"OIZ58dNapHV5upm8ATCTYU49pCRnWLUsUjSypMRTXJSK5O3nEGxxJcKhByP9VmJq8cMcxl0h826w9SamyEn7niIWkJCJ_dYRHcQcnfMQSPWr2KIOUwJTg_fz4H6p100NKDfIiTBVCsopCu5fUadAqZMpyXvcJvyrj70N6Vvp9rMUXBfLj7d7HnDtxtM_0wO0JUB8gZUJzNmGTn6283Qwandfgn1LcTH6mnja87iXsKVRSFcuLVmSXDOWbhZ3Bh0Dk9hD5ihBeK4T9DYh5TCqe0"}
```

When I'm going to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-TRANSACTION_REFUSED there's no clue there what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was business account settings. Above code is totally ok.

Setting you need to take care of is the currency. To be more specific, you need to **point all currencies you (as a business account) accept**. In this case, I have set up Euro (EUR) as a currency of the payment. Meanwhile **business account by default has only US Dollar (USD) set up as accepted currency**.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction was refused.

Perhaps it was refused in part because you specified:

```
            payment_method: {
                payee_preferred: 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED'
            }
```

And it was going to be 'pending' (not immediate), for any number of possible reasons.

Comment: I've tested with PayPal account. Which does not have pending status. According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-payment_method

Comment: The transaction may have been pending, as I said. Has nothing to do with it being an account or not.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Did you read PayPal docs I've mentioned? It says "Accepts only immediate payment from the customer. For example, credit card, PayPal balance, or instant ACH. Ensures that at the time of capture, the payment does not have the `pending` status.". And I did use PayPal (my personal, real PayPal account) to pay when testing